# Angular filter dependency with angular.module

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I've used this example in my project. (It's the `groupBy: 'team'` clause that I'm trying to make it work)

The dependency in question is [angular-filter](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js)

http://jsbin.com/weyov/45/edit?html,js,output

The difference in my code from the linked example is that I'm bootstrapping angular module so I'm getting injector errors. (I've tried to use `ng-filter`)

```
var app = angular.module("announcements", ["ng-filter"]);
app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http) {

});

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("announcements"), ["announcements"]);
```

I believe I've to pass something in the `angular.module` but not sure what value. Please advise.

[Angular Error Page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=announcements&p1=%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dng-filter%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.0%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dng-filter%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A421%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A137%250Ab%2540http%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A189%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A432%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A289%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A359%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A136%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A305%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A359%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A136%250Afb%2540http%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A43%253A165%250Ac%2540http%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A451%250AAc%2540http%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fjs%252Fapi%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A260%250Aglobal%2520code%2540http%253A%252F%252F192.168.16.101%253A3000%252Fannouncements%252Fjs%252Fapp.js%253A35%253A18%0Ahttp:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fjs%2Fapi%2Fangular.min.js:6:421%0Ahttp:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fjs%2Fapi%2Fangular.min.js:40:62%0An@http:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fjs%2Fapi%2Fangular.min.js:7:359%0Ag@http:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fjs%2Fapi%2Fangular.min.js:39:136%0Ahttp:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fjs%2Fapi%2Fangular.min.js:39:305%0An@http:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fjs%2Fapi%2Fangular.min.js:7:359%0Ag@http:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fjs%2Fapi%2Fangular.min.js:39:136%0Afb@http:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fjs%2Fapi%2Fangular.min.js:43:165%0Ac@http:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fjs%2Fapi%2Fangular.min.js:20:451%0AAc@http:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fjs%2Fapi%2Fangular.min.js:21:260%0Aglobal%20code@http:%2F%2F192.168.16.101:3000%2Fannouncements%2Fjs%2Fapp.js:35:18)

Comment: It say you need to inject `angular.filter` and you're injecting `ng-filter`?

Comment: Instead of posting a jsbin of code that works fine, but isn't yours, post a jsbin of your code, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you linked to here [angular-filter](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js) has a module named `angular.filter`, not `ng-filter` like you have in your post.  The following should get rid of your injector errors

```
var app = angular.module("announcements", ["angular.filter"]);  //changed from ng-filter
app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http) {

});

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("announcements"), ["announcements"]);
```